# iframe auto height based on content not resize when the page contain DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, resize, height

iframe auto height based on content not resize when the page contain DOM

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>

<iframe src="http://site.com/page.php" frameborder="0" width="995" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" allowtransparency="true" onload="javascript:resizeIframe(this);"></iframe>
```

And it's work perfectly until i found this problem

One of the iframe site pages contain DOM to hide and show more of text

[image]

when the user click on it..it will show more text..but the iframe will not resize and will not show the full page

[image]

I need it to work correctly

Can anyone help please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect that the DOM in the iFrame has changed and then recalc the size of your IE frame. The best way to do this is to use MutationObserver. However, that doesn't work in IE10 and below, so you have to use fallbacks.

Check out my little library that will look after all this for you.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer